# How to define dynamically the label of a 'text field' control in Orbeon Forms?

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I wish to ask you if it is possible to define dynamically the label of a 'text field' control when a form is loaded. Actually, I need to pass the label value through a **URL parameter** and use this value to define the label. Is that possible? I've made a research for a similar case but I cannot find a way to get the value of a url parameter and set it as a control's label before the form is displayed in the user.

Regards,
George

Answer (score 0):

In the Control Settings for your control, in the *Label* tab, do something as follows. Here I'm getting the value of the `foo` request parameter, but you'll most likely want to use a more meaningful name.

[image: Control settings]

That's it, really: with this, when you load your form, say with the URL `http://localhost:8080/orbeon/fr/a/a/new?foo=bar`, the control will get "bar" as its label. Also see [Template syntax](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-builder/advanced/template-syntax).

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I was looking for.

Comment: Excellent George, I am glad this worked, and thank you for the update! ‑Alex